# Model with other models as foreign keys but all inherited from the same model

Tags: django-models, database-design

I am building an e-commerce backend for bicycles using Django and DRM. I have bikes and bike parts. I want to make them all items and want to relate each bike to the parts it was built from.

Item model:

```py
class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    ID_LENGHT = 6
    
    item_id = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=ID_LENGHT,
        unique=True,
        editable=False,
        blank=False
        )  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
```

One of the parts models:

```py
class Tire(Item):    
    type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TIRE_TYPES)
```

Bike model:

```py
class Bike(Item):
    frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tires = models.ForeignKey(Tire, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wheel = models.ForeignKey(Wheel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Errors:

```
SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
bikeshop.Bike.frame: (models.E006) The field 'frame' clashes with the field 'frame' from model 'bikeshop.item'.
bikeshop.Bike.seat: (models.E006) The field 'seat' clashes with the field 'seat' from model 'bikeshop.item'.
bikeshop.Bike.wheel: (models.E006) The field 'wheel' clashes with the field 'wheel' from model 'bikeshop.item'.
```

I want to add attachments and other related items. Item model was just abstract and because of that I have an issue with shopping cart. After reading [this article](https://realpython.com/modeling-polymorphism-django-python/#concrete-base-model) I decided to make base model concrete but run into this new issue. I tried to add `related_name=` to the foreign keys but it hasn't solved the issue.

Comment: The problem is that Django already made a `OneToOneField` from `Frame` for example to `Item` and its related name has a `related_name='frame'`. But as a generale rule of thumb, I would refrain from using *concrete*: inheritance. You can make `Item` an abstract model, then it will not draw such links.

Comment: The problem is that it makes the `Order` model very bloated since I can't just create a `ManyToManyField` to the Item, but instead, I have to make a `ManyToManyField` to each child of the `Item`. I'm considering removing components from the `Bike` model altogether. Even though it is a learning project, I want it to be scalable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this happens is because you work with *concrete* inheritance. Indeed, `Item` is a *concrete* (non-*abstract*) model, and you inherit `Item` in a lot of extra models.

This means that Django will construct a model `Item` with a database table behind it, and make models like `Frame` and `Tire` with a `OneToOneField` to the `Item` named `item_ptr`. So if we would do the inheritance ourselves, it would look like:

```
class Item(TimestampedModel):
    # some data…
    pass


class Frame(models.Model):
    item_ptr = models.OneToOneFIeld(Item, related_name='tire')
    # extra fields
```

So that means there is a relation from `Item` to `Frame`: indeed `.frame` is when an `Item` is a `Frame` to obtain the data specific to the `Frame`.

This thus means that you can make extra subclasses of `Item` that will have a field to `Frame`, but you can not name these `frame`, since that name is already "taken" because of the related relation. You can for example decide to name these `component_frame`. This is the reason that `tires` is not listed: `tires` and `tire` do not conflict. So an "easy" fix is:

```
class Bike(Item):
    component_frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    component_tires = models.ForeignKey(Tire, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    # …
```

But even if you manage to do that, it is still cumbersome. Relational databases have no "native" support for subclasses. The concept of classes does not exist at all. While there are several ways to model subclassing, it nearly always results in complicated queries anyway.

If you don't have to reference to an `Item` itself, but always to "subclasses" of an `Item`, an alternative way is to make `Item` abstract, in which case it will *not* construct these `OneToOneField`. In that case there is no table named `Item`, but the `Bike`, `Tire`, etc. models will all use the fields you defined in `Item`:

```
class Item(TimeStampedModel):
    ID_LENGHT = 6
    item_id = models.CharField(
        primary_key=True,
        max_length=ID_LENGHT,
        editable=False,
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    unit_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True


class Bike(Item):
    frame = models.ForeignKey(Frame, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tires = models.ForeignKey(Tire, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    seat = models.ForeignKey(Seat, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    wheel = models.ForeignKey(Wheel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```